# Custom column inherit from parent

Tags: custom

I need to create custom column and make it so, that all the workspaces inherit it from the parent. How do I do that?

Comment: Please provide more information - do Your mean custom field type or simply a new field in the list?

Comment: I need new column like "Modified by", I need this column to show in every workspace and I have 700 workspaces. Column is used for salesforce search.

Answer (score 1):

Custom columns doesn't inherit from a parent column. You chose the data type upon creation:

[image]

Comment: So, I have about 700 workspaces and all of them need new custom field. I have to create 700 custom columns? Quite a lot of work then.

Comment: @SaulTanninen That is quite a lot of work. For the future, you typically create a template for sites with the custom column and lists that should be available. For existing workplaces you typically script it using PowerShell. See [Create Site Column in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/create-site-column-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html) as a starting point.